# How is this defined in an iterative style?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, iteration

This is the so-called recursive style:

[image]

And this is the so-called iterative style:

[image]

It seems like it is defined recursively to me. The function doesn't hide the next call of the function defined in it at all.

(SICP 95)

Comment: It seems a programming question.  Both definitions are recursive.`loop` is used for creating iterations.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Agreed. I'd call the two variants top-down and bottom-up recursion.